# Languages with a common, productive construction for marking heterogeneous groups

Tags: list-of-languages, plurality

Are there any languages with a construction similar in meaning to an associative plural or elliptical construction that's used frequently within the language? I'm particularly interested in a construction that's productive, can be used with animate or inanimate objects, and doesn't mandate a particular role for the representative (e.g. the head of a family or the leader of a group).

I'm curious whether there are any languages where it is relatively common to describe an ad hoc collection of things or people by picking a representative and combining it with some kind of grammaticalized particle or affix to refer to the whole thing. For exmaple, if it were unremarkable to refer to some silverware on a table as `the fork &c`, that would qualify. Or if it were acceptable to refer to a collection of blue and red pencils as `the blue pencils &c`, that would also count.

The WALS article on [Associative Plurals](https://wals.info/chapter/36) describes a construction that's generally similar to the additive plural called an associative plural. WALS gives the example `Tanaka-tachi (田中達)` meaning `Tanaka and her/his associates`. A construction meaning `a group of people related to person X` seems to be common cross-linguistically.

However, the WALS article goes on to make an interesting claim:

> There is only sporadic evidence for inanimate heterogeneous plurals
>   designating sets of objects closely related to each other, and this
>   pattern is never productive.

Depending on how narrowly they are defining what qualifies as an associative plural, that would suggest that a hypothetical `&c`-like construction is unattested.

[This question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/29893/how-common-is-the-elliptical-dual-or-plural-cross-linguistically) is similar, but seems to be asking mainly about the prototypical associative plural used for groups of people, which seems to be extremely common cross-linguistically.

Comment: Well, your example of silverware readily offers *ware*. You know what I mean with *wood wear*, although the term vas no currency. Ger *-Wahre* "goods" is even more productive, as is *-Gut* or plural *Güter*, chiefly refering to trade goods. The current hip collective is *stuff* "substance". It's rather the case that these become specialized terms used standing alone. *-ship* even appears as *Schöpfer* "creator god" (with uncertain etymology, though)

Comment: @vectory, I think I'm talking about something slightly different, but I don't know German so I can't say for sure. Can you use `*Bleistiftware` or `*Stiftware` to refer to a group of pens, pencils, and crayons on a table? Also, is the spelling `Ware` correct for the word you're referring to? I checked Wiktionary, which cites Duden.

Comment: No, but there already is *Schreib-Waren* "writing supplies" or *Schreib-Zeug* "writing material" as a set idiom. *Stift* is more general and might mean any stiffy stub and stubby staff. Otherwise the plural *Stift-e* is enough to denote a set.

Comment: If I understand your question maybe you refer to paucal, see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number